# Show search hit in the middle of screen for "git log"?

Tags: git

I could do search in `git log` output via `/searchpattern`, then navigate through all the hit patterns via `n` and `N`, like search in Vim. But it only shows the current line with hit pattern at the top of a screen. Most times I am more interested in content above search line (like commit hash) so I have to scroll screen via `j`/`k` manually. Is there a setting which always shows the current line in the middle of screen, or something like `set screenoff=10` in Vim to set screen offset?

Comment: `git log` uses your configured pager. The default pager is `less`, but if you have a pager you prefer that implements whatever feature you want, you can use that. But this sounds like you're solving the wrong problem: consider using `git log -G <pattern>` or `git log -S <string>`.

Comment: @torek thanks for the hint. Seems `-j` option for `less` works, even passes as command line parameter or run the command in the page.